# App is crashing after i added Recycler view to it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, navigation, drawer

Below I am attaching my codes that i have tried but still the App is crashing whenever that activity is opening. Thanks In Advance
Here Is my adapter.java file:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList;

    public CategoryAdapter(List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList) {
        this.categoryModelList = categoryModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        String icon = categoryModelList.get(position).getCategoryIconLink();
        String name = categoryModelList.get(position).getCategoryName();
        viewHolder.setCategoryName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryModelList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private ImageView categoryIcon;
        private TextView categoryName;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            categoryIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
            categoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        }

        private void setCategoryIcon()
        {
            //TODO: set category icon
        }

        private void setCategoryName(String name)
        {
            categoryName.setText(name);
        }
    }
}
```

And my xml file where i Have created RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/category_recyclerview"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the java file where i have implemented the Recycler View:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private RecyclerView categoryRecyclerView;
    private CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        categoryRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.category_recyclerview);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        categoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel("Link", "Home"));
        categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel("Link", "Electronics"));
        categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel("Link", "Appliances"));
        categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel("Link", "Furniture"));
        categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel("Link", "Fashion"));
        categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel("Link", "Gifts"));
        categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel("Link", "Sports"));
        categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel("Link", "Arts"));
        categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel("Link", "Books"));
        categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel("Link", "Shoes"));

        categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(categoryModelList);
        categoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
        categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                MainActivity.this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_frame_layout);
        setFragment(new HomeFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.main_search_icon) {
            //TODO: search
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.main_notification_icon) {
            //TODO: notification system
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.main_cart_icon) {
            //TODO: Cart
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_my_mall) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_orders) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_rewards) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_cart) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_wishlist) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_account) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(frameLayout.getId(), fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

And this is my LogCat:

```
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.project.apnidukaan, PID: 3741
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.apnidukaan/com.project.apnidukaan.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2904)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1671)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6784)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:852)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
         Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.project.apnidukaan.ui.home.HomeFragment: make sure class name exists
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadFragmentClass(FragmentFactory.java:91)
            at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:521)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$6.instantiate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2851)
            at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:132)
            at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:162)
            at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
            at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:71)
            at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:28)
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:859)
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:503)
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:460)
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:425)
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:407)
            at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:236)
            at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2586)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:838)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1133)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1393)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3205)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:134)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:336)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:995)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:995)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
            at com.project.apnidukaan.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2857)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1671)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6784)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:852)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.apnidukaan.ui.home.HomeFragment
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadClass(FragmentFactory.java:47)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadFragmentClass(FragmentFactory.java:88)
                ... 50 more
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.project.apnidukaan.ui.home.HomeFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.project.apnidukaan-Q1XVcFFx_ABsbgerU5istQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.project.apnidukaan-Q1XVcFFx_ABsbgerU5istQ==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                ... 54 more
```

```
Can anyone Please help me with this as this is my very important project
I have attached every code associated with the recycler view that i have used.
Thank you
```

Comment: It looks like you have a `<fragment>` element in the `activity_main` layout with a `class` or `android:name` attribute that points to `com.project.apnidukaan.ui.home.HomeFragment`. That's the wrong package for your `HomeFragment`, going by the given code, so it can't find that class. However, you're loading a `HomeFragment` yourself in `onCreate()`, so you likely don't need that `<fragment>` at all; just the `<FrameLayout>` for the `Fragment` container.

Comment: OK, well, that's the wrong package as far as the code in the original revision indicated.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank You sir. This helped me and now the app is working fine.

Comment: No problem. However, I just noticed the Navigation stuff in your code and trace. (Don't know how I missed that.) If you do mean to be using the Navigation component, then you shouldn't need to handle `FragmentTransaction`s yourself. The Navigation component would do that for you. If instead you want to handle the transactions yourself, then you can remove all of the Navigation stuff. I'm not sure what your desired design is, though. Anyhoo, glad you got it to stop crashing, at least. :-) Cheers!